# Slider Checkbox on modal passing Null instead of 0 or 1 to my DB when checked or unchecked

Tags: laravel

I´m trying to make an admin panel where the rights of the user are turned off and on with a switch. I can see that my data is beeing passed to the modal, but th rights on the DB are not beeing updated.

My view looks like this:

```
  <script>
    $('#edit').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
      var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
      var id = button.data('id'); // Extract info from data-* attributes
      var Admin = button.data('Admin');
      var modal = $(this);
      $('#edit_form').attr('action', '{{URL::to('/')}}/AdminPanel/'+id); 
      modal.find('#is-Admin').val(Admin);
    });
  </script>
```

and my modal looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group row">
 <label for="Admin" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{__('Admin?') }}</label>
 <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-7 col-md-6">
 <label class="switch">
  <input id='is-Admin' name='Admin' type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider round"></span>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround, giving my slider an initial value of 0 (no rights) and defining the value when checked (1), I can pass the right values to the DB.

```
  <input name='Admin' type='hidden' value='0'>
  <input id='is-Admin' name="Admin" type="checkbox" value='1'>
```